# react-bootstrap css .style adding multiple style for a button

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

I want to add multiple style from my .styl file for each button which each have different background-color.

I import the style code with

```
import mystyle from './myStyle.styl'
```

in my style file

```
:local .mybutton
   border-radius: 1px
   padding:: 3px
   margin: 0px
   font-size: 10px
   text-align: center

 :local .bluebutton
    background-color: #589652 !important

  :local .redbutton
    background-color: #289652 !important
```

the buttons are defined as

```
<ButtonToolbar>
  <Button className={mystyle.mybutton}>Blue Button</Button>
  <Button className={mystyle.mybutton}>Red Button</Button>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

I would like to do soomething like this but I have gotten it to work yet

```
<Button className="mybutton bluebutton">Blue Button</Button>
```

how do I added a second styling for color in each of my buttons?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer at this following link if someone else get stuck

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/41gu88/how_would_i_add_multiple_style_attributes_to_a/